# different conditional probabilities and their interpretation

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Say I know of a man with 3 sons.

I belive that the odds that a son has green eyes is 1/4, and 3/4 for brown.

Given that I know one son has green eyes, the probability of at least two having green eyes is:
$\frac{p(\text{2 or more have green eyes})}{p(\text{one or more has green eyes})} =\frac{1-(3/4)^3-3(1/4)*(3/4)^2}{1-(3/4)^3}$

Given that I know that the first son has green eyes, the probability of two or more having green eyes is:
$1-(3/4)^2$

The same second probability applies if I condition on the second son having green eyes, or condition on the third.

Intuitively, however, it would seem that the **first probability should be a weighted average of these 3 equal probabilities, and therefore equal to them.** But I calculated them, and that does not seem to be the case.

Could someone please shed some light on the matter?

Comment: ponderation is not a word, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean a weighted average.

Answer (score 3):

"The father with three sons of green or brown eyes" problem can be modeled by the following set of elementary events:

$$\Omega=\{(g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g),(g,b,b),(b,g,g),(b,g,b),(b,b,g),(b,b,b)\}$$
where the $i^{\text{th}}$ components of the triplets denote the eye color of the $i^{\text{th}}$ son.
What abou the probabilities assigned to these elementary events? If we assume that the eye color of the brothers is independent and that color green is of probability $\frac14$ and then color brown is of probability $\frac34$ then we have the following probabilities:

$$P:\left\{\frac1{4^3},\frac3{4^3},\frac3{4^3},\frac9{4^3},\frac3{4^3},\frac9{4^3},\frac9{4^3},\frac{27}{4^3}\right\}$$
in the order of the elementary events listed above.

**1**

> "Given that I know [at least] one son has green eyes, the probability of at least two having green eyes is"

a conditional probability of the following form:

$$P(\{(g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g),(b,g,g)\}\mid \{(g,b,b),(b,g,b),(b,b,g),(g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g),(b,g,g)\})=$$
$$=\frac{P(\{(g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g),(b,g,g)\})}{P(\{(g,b,b),(b,g,b),(b,b,g),(g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g),(b,g,g)\})}=$$
$$=\frac{\frac1{4^3}+\frac3{4^3}+\frac3{4^3}+\frac3{4^3}}{1-\frac{27}{4^3}}=\frac{10}{37}.$$

That is, the first result is OK.

**2**

> "Given that I know that the first son has green eyes, the probability of two or more having green eyes"

is a conditional probability of the following form

$$P(\{(g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g),(b,g,g)\}\mid \{(g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g),(g,b,b)\})=$$
$$=\frac{P(\{(g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g),(b,g,g)\}\cap\{(g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g),(g,b,b)\})}{P(\{(g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g),(g,b,b)\})}=$$
$$=\frac{P((g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g))}{P(\{(g,g,g),(g,g,b),(g,b,g),(g,b,b)\})}=$$
$$=\frac{\frac1{4^3}+\frac3{4^3}+\frac3{4^3}}{\frac1{4^3}+\frac3{4^3}+\frac3{4^3}+\frac9{4^3}}=\frac7{16}.$$

That is, the second result is OK as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I think  you miscalculated on the last step, and my calculation was correct.

Comment: >>> g=1/4                                                                                      
>>> b=3/4                                                                                      
>>> a=(g*g*g+g*b*g+g*g*b)
>>> b=a+g*b*b
>>> a/b ==
0.4375
>>> 1-(3/4)**2 ==
0.4375

Comment: @josinalvo: Ooops, sorry. Then your results are OK. I am going to correct my answer. Your only task is to accept it : )

Comment: :P

There is still a thing I dont understand: why can't I consider the first probability a weighted average of the second (and two equal to the second) as intuition induces me to?